# Why does my bird start flapping its wings and fall when I point the Wiimotes up?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword when trying to race on the bird, I only seem to lose altitude. How can I fly up?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you're not going fast enough while going upwards and therefor stalling (which causes you to lose lift).

You can flick your Wii remote to flap your wings and fly upwards.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, you have to swing the Wiimote side to side multiple times. Its just like a horizontal sword swing.

Comment: You just need to flick the remote in any direction really. Flick it upward, downward, one side or the other, it will flap its wings.